Mask div using SVG with filter?
I have a div, that I want to be masked by an svg containing a filter. Specifically, I have a parent SVG that has a mask containing a filter to create a cloud effect.
 <svg
    version="1.1"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    viewBox={`0 0 320 440`}
    preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice"
    className="relative block size-full max-w-[20rem] border border-red-500"
    >
      <defs>
        <filter id="displacementFilterFooter">
          <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency="0.01" numOctaves="3" result="noise" />
          <feDisplacementMap
            in="SourceGraphic"
            in2="noise"
            scale="200"
            xChannelSelector="R"
            yChannelSelector="G"
            result="displacement"
            />
          <feGaussianBlur in="displacement" stdDeviation="10" />
        </filter>
        <mask id="circleMaskFooter">
          <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="white" r="160" filter="url(#displacementFilterFooter)" />
        </mask>
      </defs>
    <svg/>

and the div i want to apply that mask to:
<foreignObject
  style={{ WebkitClipPath: 'url(#circleMaskFooter)', clipPath: 'url(#circleMaskFooter)' }}
  className="size-full border border-blue-500"
  >
    <div
    // style={{ WebkitClipPath: 'url(#circleMaskFooter)', clipPath: 'url(#circleMaskFooter)' }}
      className="pointer-events-auto relative bg-theme-primary"
    >
    <button onClick={() => updateVisisbilityHandler()} className="absolute right-0 top-0 p-2 text-white">
      <XMarkIcon className="size-14 text-white" aria-hidden="true" stroke-width="3" />
    </button>
    <div className="size-full border border-green-500">
      <NewsletterContent />
    </div>
  </div>
</foreignObject>

i have tried changing it to a div, tried putting both foreignObject and div inside and otuside the SVG with no success.

the viewBox value is not the right syntax.
